# Function-Meter which can take both 'count' and 'sum' functions, similar to FunctionTimer?

Tags: micrometer

I am puzzled by the apparent lack of a type of meter taking two methods "count" and "sum"? There is the `FunctionTimer` for the similar problem with timings, whereby you already have a statistic in the system which have a count and totalTime.

The situation I have is message sizes, which is already available in the system (ActiveMQ) expressed as a count of messages, and a total number of bytes - which I'd like to "forward" to Micrometer. I'd want to have this exposed in the same way as a `FunctionTimer` does it. E.g. with Prometheus, this ends up as a "summary" with both "count" + "sum" series.

`FunctionCounter` is close, but it only takes the "sum" part, not count.

Comment: Can you use a FunctionCounter for the "sum" part and another one for the "count"?